# how to run long process in background in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, console-application

I have developed a web application in Asp.net core 3.1.(MVC template) and I have a code that will run for a days and make a service call and log data to the database. My problem is that server time out is only for 60 minutes and it shuts down my process after 60 minutes. Is there any way I can still run process even if browser is closed.

Someone suggested me that my Web application design has a flow and I should use a console application to archive this.I am not sure is it something I should do or there is some better way.

Comment: i think [HostedServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) are what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann. If I use HostedServices, will my code keep running even if I close the browser?

Comment: it starts when you start your app, it stops when you stop your app. it even works with no user accessing the web service.

Comment: What do you mean by a server timeout. Do you mean the server stops after 60 mins? I haven't seen such a behaviour till now. As far as I understand if a .net core web application is hosted in Kestrel it never stops. Can you give us more information on how your application is hosted.